# How to check ReactDOM.render method to be called with a react component argument?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, react-dom

Code here:

`index.tsx`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export function Loading(props) {
  return <div {...props}>loading...</div>;
}

export class MyComponent extends Component {
  static show() {
    const container = document.createElement('div');
    container.classList.add('loading-container');
    document.body.appendChild(container);
    ReactDOM.render(<Loading className="loading" />, container);
  }
  render() {
    return <div>my component</div>;
  }
}
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Loading, MyComponent } from './';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const renderSpy = jest.spyOn(ReactDOM, 'render');
    MyComponent.show();
    const loadingContainer = document.body.querySelector('.loading-container');
    // 1. failed
    // expect(renderSpy).toBeCalledWith(expect.any(Loading), loadingContainer);

    // 2. TS type error
    // expect(renderSpy).toBeCalledWith(Loading, loadingContainer);

    // 3. TS type error
    // expect(renderSpy).toBeCalledWith(<Loading />, loadingContainer);
  });
});
```

I have tried three ways to assert that `renderSpy` to be called with the `Loading` component. But none of them work.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's you're just missing the `className="loading"` in `<Loading />`:

```
import { Loading, MyComponent } from "./index";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

describe("MyComponent", () => {
  it("spying on ReactDOM", () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(ReactDOM, "render");
    MyComponent.show();

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      <Loading className="loading" />,
      document.body.querySelector(".loading-container")
    );
  });
});
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can mock ReactDOM instead of spying on it:

```
import { Loading, MyComponent } from "./index";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

jest.mock("react-dom", () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  __SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED: {
    Events: [],
  },
  createPortal: jest.fn(),
  findDOMNode: jest.fn(),
  flushSync: jest.fn(),
  hydrate: jest.fn(),
  render: jest.fn(),
  unmountComponentAtNode: jest.fn(),
  unstable_batchedUpdates: jest.fn(),
  unstable_createPortal: jest.fn(),
  unstable_renderSubtreeIntoContainer: jest.fn(),
  version: "17.0.1",
}));

describe("MyComponent", () => {
  it("mocking ReactDOM", () => {
    MyComponent.show();

    expect(ReactDOM.render).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      <Loading className="loading" />,
      document.body.querySelector(".loading-container")
    );
  });
});
```

[image]

Comment: You are right. The issue is the TS type error. I have to type cast like this: `(<Loading className="loading" />) as any`